# How to avoid error in Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

This is my program

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url="http://www.moneycontrol.com/commodity/gold-price.html#05oct2013"
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
```

It is giving following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\bs4\__init__.py", line 183, in __init__
    self._feed()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\bs4\__init__.py", line 197, in _feed
    self.builder.feed(self.markup)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\bs4\builder\_htmlparser.py", line 156, in feed
    raise e
HTMLParseError: malformed start tag, at line 102, column 168
```

While

```
url="http://www.moneycontrol.com/commodity/"
```

is not giving any error

Answer (score 0):

Both sites parse for me with your code (with html.parser or lxml as a parser). Which versions of Python and BeautifulSoup are you using? You could try parsing with a [different parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use).

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 and BeautifulSoup version 4.3.1

Comment: Works here on Python 2.7.5 and BeautifulSoup 4.3.1. Try installing lxml or html5lib, see if it helps.

Comment: I have install html5lib and still getting the error ------------------`>>> import html5lib
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html5lib")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\bs4\__init__.py", line 152, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))
FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html5lib. Do you need to install a parser library?`

Comment: Did you maybe install bs 4.3.1 over 3.1? There was a [known error](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/3.1-problems.html)  in 3.1 with "malformed start tag". I'd suggest removing bs and installing it again.